# How to set two sliders connecting to each lines in graph using plotly.js?

Tags: graph, charts, slider, plotly, plotly.js

How to set two sliders connecting to each lines in graph using plotly.js?

Here I attached the code.

And the only one line can be moved using two sliders.

How can I match each slider to each line?

`trace1` is red one and `tarce2` is blue one.

I want to find attributes that can connecting slider with each trace.

```js
  var length;
  var sliderData = ['1.0','1.1','1.2','1.3','1.4','1.5'];
  var sliderData2 = ['0.5','0.6','0.7','0.8','0.9','1.0'];
  var rawData = {
    name:['0.5','0.6','0.7','0.8','0.9','1.0','1.1','1.2','1.3','1.4','1.5', ],
    date:[{y: [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]},{y: [0.6, 0.6, 0.6]},{y: [0.7, 0.7, 0.7]},{y: [0.8, 0.8, 0.8]},{y: [0.9, 0.9, 0.9]}, {y: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]},{y: [1.1, 1.1, 1.1]},{y: [1.2, 1.2, 1.2]},{y: [1.3, 1.3, 1.3]},{y: [1.4, 1.4, 1.4]},{y: [1.5, 1.5, 1.5]}]
  }
  var frames = [];
  var steps = [];
  var steps2 = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    frames.push({
       name: rawData.name[i],
       data: [rawData.date[i]]
    })
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    steps.push({
       label: sliderData[i],
       method: 'animate',
       args: [[sliderData[i]], {
         mode: 'immediate',
         frame: {redraw: false, duration: 500},
         transition: {duration: 500}
       }]      
    })
    steps2.push({
       label: sliderData2[i],
       method: 'animate',
       args: [[sliderData2[i]], {
         mode: 'immediate',
         frame: {redraw: false, duration: 500},
         transition: {duration: 500}
       }]      
    })
  }
 var trace1 = {
      name : "trace1",
      x: [1, 2, 3],
   y: [1, 1, 1],
   line: {
    color: 'red',
    simplify: false,
   }
   };
   var trace2 = {
      name : "trace2",
      x: [1, 2, 3],
   y: [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
   line: {
     color: 'blue',
     simplify: false,
   }
   };
    //slider for trace1
    var slide1 = {
     active:1,
     pad: {t: 60},
     x: 0,
     len: 0.5,
     currentvalue: {
       xanchor: 'right',
       prefix: 'RBP: ',
       font: {
         color: '#888',
         size: 15
       }
     },
     transition: {duration: 10},
     steps: steps
   }
    //slider for trace2
   var slide2 = {
     pad: {t: 60},
     x: 0.5,
     len: 0.5,
     currentvalue: {
       xanchor: 'right',
       prefix: 'RMP: ',
       font: {
         color: '#888',
         size: 15
       }
     },
     transition: {duration: 10},
     steps: steps2
   }
Plotly.plot('graph', {
 data: [trace1,trace2],
 layout: {
    xaxis: {
      range: [1, 3],
    },
    yaxis: {
      range: [0, 2]
    },
   sliders: [slide1, slide2],
 },
 frames: frames
});
```

```css
 #graph{
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
   <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="graph"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to more detail please "Run code" !!